# Gradle build error with NDK version - ndk.dir version which disagrees with android.ndkVersion

Tags: android, android-ndk, android-gradle-plugin

After upgrading the Gradle plugin and Android Studio 4.2.1. I face this error while building the C++ library.

```
Caused by: com.android.builder.errors.EvalIssueException: NDK from ndk.dir at D:\Sdk\ndk\18.0.5002713 had version [18.0.x] which disagrees with android.ndkVersion [22.1.x]
```

Answer (score 9):

Very simple solution. Remove `ndk.dir` from local.properties,

and declare ndkVersion inside build.gradle in app/library level

```
android {
    compileSdkVersion 30
    ndkVersion "18.0.5002713"
    ...
}
```

Thanks

Comment: For Flutter users, do not remove 'ndk.dir' at local.properties. If u remove it, it wouldn't create 3 folders at '[YOUR_PROJECT]\app\build\intermediates\merged_native_libs\release\out\lib' for native debug symbols.